# Animate NavigationBar title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation

I am using a nested navigation controller with the navigation bar hidden in a view that is added via the main navigation controller. Everything works perfect except when I change section and set the title of the root navigation controller it doesnt animate.

Is there anyway to animate navigation bar titles?

Answer (score 3):

New answer to an old question, but still applies. If you want to animate between different title strings, use the following:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
fadeTextAnimation.duration = 0.5;
fadeTextAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation: fadeTextAnimation forKey: @"fadeText"];
self.navigationItem.title = "My new title";
```

You can adjust the duration and set a timing function to suit, of course.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, nothing on the UINavigationBar/UINavigationItem can be animated except the size of the bar, and the methods which set the bar items and take an 'animated:' parameter.

Answer (score -1):

just use the UIView animation code. don't know if it works 100% but it should! so in the method you are changing the title do `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{}]` and change the title in there. hope this works for you!